# Why angularjs will invoke function `name()` twice?

Tags: angularjs

The code is simple:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker" >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>document.write("<base href=\"" + document.location + "\" />");</script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  Hello {{name()}}!
</body>
</html>
<script>
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name= function() {
    console.log("---name---:" + new Date());
    return "Freewind";
  };
});

</script>
```

You can see there is a `name` function and we invoke it in the body only one time. But in the console, it prints twice of `---name---:`:

```
---name---:Wed Feb 20 2013 14:38:12 GMT+0800 (中国标准时间)
---name---:Wed Feb 20 2013 14:38:12 GMT+0800 (中国标准时间)
```

You can see a live demo here: http://plnkr.co/edit/tb8RpnBJZaJ73V73QISC?p=preview

Why the function `name()` has been invoked two times?

Comment: it is very difficult sometimes to get to the *exact* question you are looking for. Thx for this!

Comment: Though you can restrict it to call only once by using init variable
ref: http://plnkr.co/edit/l57V2rzX51JumtAtWXBN?p=preview
hope this helps.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In AngularJS, anything wrapped in double curly braces is an [expression](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) that gets evaluated *at least once* during the digest cycle.

AngularJS works by running the digest cycle continuously until nothing has changed. That's how it ensures the view is up-to-date. Since you called a function, it's running it once to get a value and then a second time to see that nothing has changed. On the next digest cycle, it will run at least once again.

It's generally a good idea to only call idempotent methods (like `name`) from the template for this very reason.

Comment: +1, also to make it clear: angularjs may call any function bound in the view at **any** point during digest phase and **multiple** digest phases might be executed. It makes **no guarantee** about the number of calls.

Comment: Right! The *only* thing guaranteed is that it will run *at least* once.

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller thank you for this. Is there a way to bind the result of some computation to a view without using a method call in the brackets? For example: http://plnkr.co/edit/cFHa6uhYbZc6QwNoLw10?p=preview

Comment: @desbo You can manually maintain a scope variable, which is usually the preferred approach if the method performs any computation; the controller then changes the scope variable as necessary (manually or through watches). But the reason your Plunker doesn't work is that `count` is *assigned*, not referenced. Demo of both: http://plnkr.co/edit/miXH6b6HsRWwDNKVgiPP?p=preview

Comment: Ah, thanks. So would you advise against exposing services directly in controllers, as I did, and creating wrappers for the service methods in the controller instead?

Comment: That can depend upon particulars. *In general*, I place services on scopes that represent *things*, but I do not place any services on the scope that represent *actions*. That is, a `userService` would not go on the scope, but a `currentUser` would. This is a compromise for separation of concerns. I will note, however, that there is some disagreement here as to the best practice.

Comment: I am new user of AngularJS. I find this wird. So, all controller methods should be idempotent ?
Please share documentation if you do have? - thx

Comment: @minchiya - All controller methods being idempotent would not be a good rule of thumb, but one should definitely keep performance in mind when choosing to have methods that are evaluated during the digest. Not all controller methods are; only those bound as expressions will be evaluated during the digest. What kind of documentation are you looking for?

Comment: Thank you. Concerning documentation, I started using angularJs. But I need to better understand what is happening behind the scene, like the digest cycle... If you know a nice tutorial I would be grateful

Comment: The [guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide) has a collection of pretty good tutorials (including an official one). Also check out the great videos on  [egghead](https://egghead.io/). But if you're really looking to learn about the *internals*, the guide pages on [bootstrapping](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap) and the [compiler](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler) are must-reads.

Comment: You can surely get rid of double execution of such functions by adding a init variable to carry its value.
ref: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39408368/1666582

Comment: @saurabh: I agree with using variables instead of functions for all but trivial things. However, it does *not* prevent the expression from being evaluated more than once. Whatever is within the curly braces will be evaluated twice. If it's a function, it will be called twice, but if it's a variable, its value will still be pulled *twice* - because something else in the cycle could have changed it.