# AngularJS ng-repeat loops double than actual length of records

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I saw many questions related to 'dirty check'. Want to confirm my below issue is due to that.

I have JSON string from RestService: Basically two records

```
[{"intRowId":111,"fltAmt":6.0,"intCnt":2,"category":{"intCatId":2,"strCatName":"Rent"},"monthYear":"2016-01-01"},
{"intRowId":112,"fltAmt":3.0,"intCnt":1,"category":{"intCatId":3,"strCatName":"Phone"},"monthYear":"2016-01-01"}]
```

I have ng-repeat in HTML page: I am calling a method AssignValues.

```
<tr ng-repeat="op in resultReport">
        <td>{{$index+1}}{{resultReport.length}}{{AssignValues(op.fltAmt,$index,op.monthYear)}}</td>
        <td>{{op.fltAmt|currency}}</td>
        <td>{{op.intCnt}}</td>
        <td>{{op.category.strCatName}}</td>
        <td>{{op.monthYear}}</td>
      </tr>
```

AssignValues in my Controller: This prints four times.

```
$scope.AssignValues = function(amt,ind,mYr){
        $log.log(amt);
    }
```

Actually I have two records in JSON, but the function prints the values repeated more than actual length. Instead of just 6 and 3, it prints 6,3,6,3. Screen shot is attached below. Any one please help me to understand this.

[image]

Comment: Function must be getting called twice!

Comment: it is by design in angular 1x, dont call function directly from template.

Comment: Thanks @NitinVarpe for quick answer. I edited the question. I meant that instead of two records it actually prints 4 times.

Comment: @YOU, I could manage it by passing the $index. But wanted to clarify whether it is expected or ng-repeat has different variations.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987277/function-called-multiple-times-in-angularjs-repeat-section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The digest loop consists in evaluating the expressions until their values are stable. To know if they're stable, angular needs to evaluate them  twice, to test if the value obtained from the first evaluation is the same as the value obtained from the second one.

So what you see is expected and normal.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Any reference could be really helpful

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest

Comment: I never knew ! Thanks.