# Controller returning value multiple times

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I'm inserting the `src` atturbute for an `<iframe>` using AngularJS.

For some reason though, whenever I call grab this value it is returned multiple times.  I know this because I was checking using `console.log(src)` to debug before I got the solution working.

This minor glitch doesn't seem to be causing any errors (or slowing my application down), but I'm curious to know what's happening?

---

## Update

I have reduced the code in my controller by moving the bulk of the work to my custom `recentStations` service (available if required).

The result within the HTML view is still the same, as is the behaviour of returning multiple results.

---

## Controller

```
app.controller('contentCtrl', ['$scope', 'recentStations', function($scope, recentStations){

    $scope.getCurrentSrc = function(){
        return recentStations.getCurrentSrc();
    };
    
}]);
```

---

## HTML

```
<div id="content" data-ng-controller="contentCtrl">
    <iframe data-ng-src="{{ getCurrentSrc() }}" seamless></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: $sce could cause that. What's happening inside trustAsResourceUrl?

Comment: It sounds like the confusing is that  `scope.getCurrentSrc` is being called multiple times. I'd expect it to be called once per `$digest` cycle, which will be several times on load, plus again every time Angular decides that some thing interesting has happened.

Comment: You can get hint http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973792/why-angularjs-will-invoke-function-name-twice

Comment: @schlingel - `$sce` is not the culprit, the behaviour still occurs even if you just return a simple `Hello World` string. Thanks.

Comment: @Vineet - Thanks for the link, I'll have a look through.

Comment: @DRobinson - Thanks, your description seems to tie in with the link provided by `Vineet`.

Comment: Yep, I think it's a fairly common confusion when starting with Angular. If it's a problem for you, and you want to prevent it, you can bind to a variable in your view, rather than a function call (like a `$scope.src` kind of thing). Then in the controller you'll just have to watch the appropriate pieces of `src` to rebuild it when necessary.

Comment: @DRobinson - Thanks, a `watch` is what I'm looking in to currently.  In this instance, the app is fairly lightweight so I doubt this behaviour will impact performance, but I'd rather do it properly so that going forward I don't have this problem when performance is more critical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A potential way to work around the additional function calls is to bind to a simple value, in your case the `src`, and use a `$watch` on dependant values to rebuild it.

Here's an example for your controller:

```
$scope.$watch(getLink, buildSource);

function getLink(){
    return recentStations.getCurrent().link;
}

function buildSource(link){
    var url = 'http://iris2.rail.co.uk/tiger/';
    var src = url + link;

    $scope.src = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
};
```

The HTML would bind as follows:

```
<iframe data-ng-src="{{ src }}" seamless></iframe>
```

However, you're still doing a (smaller) function call every $digest; now it's the `getLink` function called every time. This is because you appear to have to call `recentStations.getCurrent()` to get the link. If there's a way for you to bind its value to src, it can be simply checked every $digest cycle.

Comment: Thank you, that's really helpfull.  I've had to amend for my usage as I've changed my requirements slightly, but your answer works perfectly for my original question.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is caused by angularjs dirty checking.
AngularJS implements dirty checking for two way data binding.

Comment: Thanks.  Any suggestions as to how I can avoid this behavior?  Note that I've updated the code in my question.